# Is there a Hopf algebra-style description of chain complexes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

An [old chestnut](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25873/geometric-interpretation-of-filtered-rings-and-modules/25888#25888) is that filtered objects are the same as sheaves over $\mathbb A^1 / \mathbb G_m$.

**Question:** Is there a similar description of chain complexes?

More precisely, if $\mathcal C$ is a category, then define the category of *filtered objects* in $\mathcal C$ to be the functor category $Fil(\mathcal C) = Fun(\mathbb Z, \mathcal C)$, where $\mathbb Z$ is the integers regarded as a poset. Then if $X$ is a scheme, there is a canonical equivalence $Fil(QCoh(X)) \simeq QCoh(X \times \mathbb A^1 / \mathbb G_m)$, where $\mathbb G_m$ acts on $\mathbb A^1$ in the usual way. What this says is that $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant sheaves on $\mathbb A^1 \times X$ are the same as filtered sheaves on $X$. As $\mathbb G_m$-actions are the same as gradings, this says in other words that a graded object equipped with an an endomorphism of degree 1 is the same as a filtered object.

I'd like a similar description of the category of chain complexes $Ch(QCoh(X)) \simeq QCoh(X \times S)$, where $S$ is some fixed stack, probably a quotient $S = T / G$ for some scheme $T$ and some action by a group scheme $G$.

**Note:** I believe that if $\mathcal C$ is stable, then $Fil(\mathcal C) \simeq Ch(\mathcal C)$ via some sort of $\infty$-categorical Dold-Kan correspondence (at any rate, I'm quite sure this is true if we talk about nonnegatively-graded chain complexes and nonnegative filtrations). So the stack $S$ will have to be derived-equivalent to $\mathbb A^1 / \mathbb G_m$, but perhaps not equivalent in an underived sense.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in [the work of Balmer et al](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~balmer/Pubfile/TTG.pdf) on Tensor Triangulated Categories. Briefly, a space is associated with such a category. Note that filtered objects carry a natural tensor structure. Without a tensor structure, it is not obvious where the product/co-product for your Hopf-like structure will come from.

Comment: Unless I’m severely misunderstanding your question, it seems that one candidate for your S is BG_a^#, where G_a^# is the divided power hull  of the origin in G_a. (This’ll recover cochain complexes, corresponding to complete filtered objects.) This is coming from the fact that G_a^# is Cartier dual to the formal completion of G_a at the origin.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the classifying stack of the semidirect product G_a^# x| G_m, where G_m is acting with weight 1.

Comment: @skd I'd love to hear more about this! I don't understand the role played by Cartier duality here, for one thing.

Comment: For my own reference, I want to record Aaron Mazel-Gee's observation on Discord that this stuff is related to Khovanov's [Hopfological Algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1814)

Comment: @TimCampion am I missing something that all the answers so far give geometric objects over $\mathbb Z$, so they'd work for something like $\mathbb Z$-linear stable $\infty$ categories, rather than arbitrary infinity categories? For example, in spectra, filtered objects are sheaves over $\mathbb A^1/ \mathbb G_m$, where $\mathbb A^1 = Spec(\mathbb S[\mathbb N]), \mathbb G_, = Spec(\mathbb S[\mathbb Z])$. Over the sphere it's not so clear to me what Achim's $\Lambda$ should be, even less clear what Sanath's $\mathbb G_a^\#$ should be....

Comment: Ah perhaps you were not asking about stable $\infty$-categories in the first place...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be $\operatorname{Spec}(\Lambda)/\mathbb{G}_m$, where $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}[d]/d^2$ and the $\mathbb{G}_m$ action encodes the grading with $d$ in degree $-1$? This is just the observation that chain complexes are the same as graded modules over an exterior algebra in a degree $-1$ generator, similar to how the $\mathbb{A}^1/\mathbb{G}_m$ description of filtered objects relates to their description as graded modules over a polynomial algebra $\mathbb{Z} [\tau]$.

Comment: Can one recover Dold-Kan from this via some form of Koszul duality ? (I'm thinking that $\Lambda$ looks a lot like $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z[\tau]}\mathbb Z$, up to $d$ being in degree $1$ rather than $-1$)

Comment: Probably! I'm not super convinced that the equivalence between filtered objects and cochain complexes should be called Dold-Kan, shouldn't that refer to something with simplicial objects? In any case, It's been written up by Stefano Ariotta in https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01017. He doesn't express it in terms of graded modules and instead makes a statement about functor categories, but it looks like the type of argument you're suggesting. (The $+1$ rather than $-1$ corresponds to the fact that cochain complexes appear)

Comment: Oh yeah you're absolutely right that I should not call this Dold-Kan :D I hadn't read Stefano's paper, I was just aware of it, but thanks !

Comment: Wow, that's obvious in retrospect -- thanks! I wonder now about a "geometric interpretation"... $Spec(\Lambda)$ is somehow related to tangent spaces...

Comment: It looks like I understood more about this a year ago than I do now! There was a [discussion](https://discord.com/channels/801815065165955143/817078280392802395/964817140437893150) on the algebraic topology discord about this. See [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5323/2362) for an invite link.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Another reason for it not being Dold–Kan is that, the base category should be stable for this equivalence, while for Dold–Kan, the (weakly idempotent-complete) additivity suffices.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\AA}{\mathbf{A}}\newcommand{\GG}{\mathbf{G}}\newcommand{\Mod}{\mathrm{Mod}}\newcommand{\fil}{\mathrm{fil}}\newcommand{\QCoh}{\mathrm{QCoh}} \newcommand{\spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}$Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and consider $\hat{\GG}_a/\GG_m$ over $R$, where the $\GG_m$-action on $\GG_a = \spec(R[t])$ has weight $1$. Then the ($\infty$-)category of complete filtered $R$-modules is equivalent to $\QCoh(\hat{\GG}_a/\GG_m)$, i.e., the category of quasicoherent sheaves over $\GG_a/\GG_m$ whose pullback to $\GG_a$ is $t$-complete. Let $\GG_a^\sharp$ denote the PD-hull $\spec(R[\frac{x^n}{n!}])$. Then the pairing $\GG_a^\sharp \times \hat{\GG}_a \to \GG_m$ sending $(x, t) \mapsto e^{xt}$ exhibits $\GG_a^\sharp$ as the Cartier dual of $\hat{\GG}_a$. This pairing is $\GG_m$-equivariant as long as the coordinate $x$ on $\GG_a^\sharp$ has weight $-1$.
General principles of Cartier duality now imply that $\QCoh(\hat{\GG}_a/\GG_m)$ is equivalent to $\QCoh((B\GG_a^\sharp)/\GG_m)$, where this equivalence swaps the usual tensor product with convolution. (This is from my comment.) Now, $B\GG_a^\sharp$ is affine (as a derived stack), and $R\Gamma(B\GG_a^\sharp; \mathcal{O}) \cong R[d]/d^2$ where $d$ is in degree $-1$. So $(B\GG_a^\sharp)/\GG_m = \mathrm{Spec}(R[d]/d^2)/\GG_m$, and one recovers Achim Krause's answer.

As for the relation to tangent spaces: indeed, the appearance of $B\GG_a^\sharp$ in both places is not a coincidence. Namely, if $X$ is a (smooth, say) $R$-scheme, the mapping stack $\mathrm{Map}(B\GG_a^\sharp, X)$ can be identified with $\spec_{\mathcal{O}_X}\left(\bigoplus_{j\geq 0} \Omega^j_{X/R}[j]\right) = BT_X^\sharp$, where $T_X^\sharp$ is the PD-hull of the zero section in the tangent bundle of $X$. See, e.g., Section 2.5 of [https://www.math.ias.edu/~bhatt/teaching/mat549f22/lectures.pdf](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Ebhatt/teaching/mat549f22/lectures.pdf) . This mapping stack has a natural $B(\GG_a^\sharp\rtimes \GG_m)$-action, placing $\Omega^j_{X/R}[j]$ in weight $j$; writing $B\GG_a^\sharp = \mathrm{Spec}(R[d]/d^2)$ with $d$ in weight $-1$ and homological degree $-1$, the resulting coaction of $R[d]/d^2$ corresponds to the de Rham differential.
Under these Koszul/Cartier duality identifications, this object corresponds to the Hodge filtration $\Omega^{\geq \star}_{X/R}$ on the algebraic de Rham complex. (I just want to mention that this perspective is useful in that it can be generalized to other situations, where one replaces $\hat{\GG}_a$ by a general $1$-dimensional formal group over $R$. The resulting category of filtered spectra with its symmetric monoidal structure encodes the Leibniz rule on the $q$-de Rham complex in the case of the rescaled multiplicative group law $x + y + (q-1) xy$, and more generally complexes studied in my joint work https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.04739 .)

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting! I should learn more about Cartier duality. One idea I have in mind is that the functor $R \mapsto D(R)$, might be the "height zero case" of some more general family of functors $CRing \to Pr^L_{st}$. It sounds like this thought might be related to the paper you link? Correspondingly, the functor $R \mapsto HR$ might be the "height zero case" of some more general family of functors $CRing \to CAlg(Spt)$...

Comment: I guess what I'm calling Cartier duality between G_a-hat and BG_a^# is just Koszul duality between R[[t]] and R[d]/d^2, so it might not really be necessary to think about it in terms of Cartier duality. I'm not sure what the family of functors CRing --> CAlg(Sp) you have in mind is supposed to be, can you elaborate?

Comment: Start with $R \mapsto QCoh(Spec R \times S)$ for one of these variant stacks $S$ coming from FGLs like you say.  Then take "the stable module category / singularity category construction" (or some version thereof)-- localize the 1-category $QCoh(Spec R \times S)$ to kill the dualizable objects or something like that to obtain a stable symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category. (Does this track so far with what you have in mind?) I'm then wildly speculating that the resulting sym mon $\infty$-category might be of the form $Mod_E$ for some $E \in CAlg(Spt)$ and maybe $E$ is even functorial in $R$.

Comment: I suppose I don't want to kill all dualizable objects -- just the projectives, maybe.